# illegalArgumentExeption al agregar un internal frame en un frame

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente exepcion

> Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Lo único que quiero es agregar un internal frame a un frame principal

```
InternalFrame internalframe= new internalframe();
this.add(internalframe);
Internalframe.show();
```

Pero el código me arroja ese error, pero además tengo otro proyecto de prueba y lo agrega y muestra perfectamente

Comment: Prueba arreglar esta linea InternalFrame internalframe = new InternalFrame(); y esta otra internalframe.show();

Comment: La línea solo es ilustrativa, allí en realidad tengo es MostrarPerfil mostrar=new MostrarPerfil();

Comment: El error que lanza es por pasar un argumento ilegal, comprueba que tipo soporta el metodo add() y si el valor que le estas pasando es el correcto

Comment: Lo entiendo, por eso dije lo de que tengo otro proyecto dónde pruebo eso, y de la misma forma acepta y muestra el frame, y todas las guías de internet dicen lo mismo

Comment: Cuando escribes esta línea `this.add(internalframe);` **this** hace referencia a la clase actual, en la que estás trabajando. Puedo saber si hereda de alguna otra clase. Podrías poner la definición de la clase?

Comment: El this hace referencia a un jframe dónde quiere que se agregue el internalframe